# how to export a promise to be reused elsewhere in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

In postman I get an error: TypeError: ClientPromise.then is not a function.

```
*auth.js*

const Client = require("@x/nr");

module.exports = {
  ClientPromise: function(options) {
    return Client.authenticate(options); <--- (this returns a promise)
  }
}
```

Here is where I would like to call the promise from auth.js

```
*API.js*
var ClientPromise = require('../config/auth').ClientPromise

module.exports = {
  findOneClientProblem: function(req, res) {
    ClientPromise.then(function (client) {
      const Problem = client.Problem;
      return Problem.findOne(req.params.radarProblemID)
    }).then(function (result){
      return res.json(result)
    });
  }
}
```

It works when I have all of it in one file like this.

```
const Client = require("@x/nr");

const ClientPromise = Client.authenticate(options); <--- (this returns a promise)

module.exports = {
  findOneClientProblem: function(req, res) {
    ClientPromise.then(function (client) {
      const Problem = client.Problem;
      return Problem.findOne(req.params.radarProblemID)
    }).then(function (result){
      return res.json(result)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Invoke the function (in the first example - do `ClientPromise: function(options) { .... }()` if you want to share the promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In API.js, you have to actually call the `ClientPromise()` function.  You are just obtaining a reference to the function, but not actually calling it, thus you don't have a promise.

Your variable `ClientPromise` just contains a reference to the function itself.  To execute that function, you need to call it:

```
ClientPromise(options).then(...)
```

Here is that change in context:

```
// *API.js*
var ClientPromise = require('../config/auth').ClientPromise

module.exports = {
  findOneClientProblem: function(req, res) {
    ClientPromise(/* put options here */).then(function (client) {
      const Problem = client.Problem;
      return Problem.findOne(req.params.radarProblemID)
    }).then(function (result){
      return res.json(result)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @DavidTrinh - Did this answer your question?